# How to pass Spark configuration parameters to DBT?

Tags: apache-spark, dbt

I am using DBT to connect to AWS/EMR. I am able to run Spark/SQL queries but where do I set parameters like for example `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`, that in normal code you will pass with:

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1200")
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I do not get any answer here, I write what I think is the way at the moment (but repeat, not sure if it is the right way to go):

```
{{ config(
    materialized='table',
    pre_hook=['SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1200'],
    ...
)}}
```